# C# LINQ, if (time) not found, select previous/copy previous result

Tags: c#, linq, time, group-by

Let's say I have a `List<Type>` and a `Type` with the properties:

```
public DateTime OriginalDateTime { get; set; }
public double RoundedTime { get; }
public int MyValue { get; set; }
```

And that class contains a constructor:

```
public Match(DateTimeOffset dateTime, int bid, int ask, int volume)
{
            DateTime = dateTime;
            RoundedTime = Math.Round(Math.Ceiling(dateTime.ToTimeStamp() / 60) * 60); // Round to nearest minute
            Bid = bid;
            Ask = ask;
            Volume = volume;
}
```

Now using `LINQ` and `GroupBy` I get all the results grouped by `RoundedTime`. No problem, however, I want to check if there is a result for every minute (so for an hour of data, the `GroupBy` should return 60 results).

Preferably, when a minute is missing from the `LINQ` result, I'd like to use the previous value (let's say minute 30 is missing, fill it with the data of minute 29).

Now I'm wondering if this is even possible with `LINQ`.

Comment: Yes, e.g. you could use an Enumerable.Range to generate the 0-60 sequence and for each one look up the corresponding value or max value <= current as a mapping. But you might do better writing a yield function to walk the (sorted) list and fill in the gaps.

Comment: `TakeWhile()` where minute < 30 (or whatever), then `LastOrDefault`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to achieve this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, MyType>> mygrouping = new List<MyType>().GroupBy(x => x.Key); // this is your grouped list

var allData = Enumerable.Range(0, 60) // here you take 60 values (0-59)
            .Select(
              actualKey =>
              {
                  var p = mygrouping.SingleOrDefault(y => y.Key == actualKey);
                  int counter = actualKey;
                  while (p == null && counter >= 0) // as long as the value is null and the counter is greater or equal to 0
                      p = mygrouping.SingleOrDefault(y => y.Key == counter--);
                  return new KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<MyType>>(actualKey, p.Select(v => v)); // return the data of the last value
              });
```

this is just a little help, you need to modify the code to make it work with yours I guess. AND: there are more performant ways I guess

Comment: Looks great. Since performance is somewhat important, I guess it's better to write a method instead of a 'single' LINQ query?

Comment: @Viletung yeah, for debugging-purposes and readability I guess it's better to write a function than a single linq.

Comment: also for performance right, or is LINQ faster? Perhaps I should do some research.

Comment: plus, there is a `while (p == null && counter >= 0) ...` in. maybe you find a better variant, when you are in a function, you can store the last key you found  in your grouping. then you can take that instead of iterating back with that while. - then this is much better for performance, too.